# TabviewController How to show the unread messages like as badges?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstabviewcontroller

[image]

Here i am using the 4 tabViews, third one is chat button so here user unread messages how to show the badges

in #import "HomeTabViewController.h"

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *badgeVal = @"5";
  [[[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2]  tabBarItem] setBadgeValue:badgeVal];
  }
```

Comment: You are using TabbarController ?

Comment: yes i am using Tabviewcontroller

Comment: yes 1st tab is peopleVC 2nd is eventVC 3rd is ChatVC 4th is ProfileVC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to simply set [`badgeValue`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbaritem/1617065-badgevalue?language=objc) property of `tabBarItem` for that.

```
NSString *badgeVal = @"5"; //Unread message count
[[[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2] tabBarItem] setBadgeValue:badgeVal];
```

**Note :** I have access 3rd `ViewController` using `objectAtIndex:2` because you want to set badge for the 3rd `UITabBarItem`.

Comment: i have one more doubt , i have one button when i click that button it is going to chatVC how ? under button what code i write please help me

Comment: @Nirav How can we use this for barbuttonitems?

Comment: @Himanth There isn't direct way to set badge for bar button items, you need to make custom view for that and need to make uibarbuttonitem object from it

Answer (score 1):

Well, just use the `badgeValue` property of the `UITabbarItem`:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbaritem/1617065-badgevalue

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
NSString *badgeVal = @"5"; //Unread message count
[[self navigationController] tabBarItem].badgeValue = badgeVal;
```

or

`[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:<your item position>] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",badgeVal]]`;

Comment: Than you can create your custom tab bar and manage all thing what you want. I used my custom tabbarview and manage it easily.

Comment: how to create the custom tabbar can u help me please

Comment: Yes sure send me ur email i send u a demo project. Don't forget to give a rate.

Comment: gsivakumar54@gmail.com